# change postgresql schema on the fly

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenancy app with Spring Boot. Recently, I am trying to switch to PostgreSQL over MySQL. I want to use same database but different schema. However, I couldn't find a way to change schema on Spring Boot. On MySQL, it is possible via jdbc url by replacing the database name. On Postgre, I tried using currentSchema but it doesn't work. What could be the issue or how else can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The search_path setting in PostgreSQL controls the order in which schemas are searched when resolving names. By default, it is set to "$user", meaning that names will be resolved in the current user's schema first, followed by the public schema.

You can override the default search_path by setting it in your application.properties file. The example above sets it to "my_schema". This will cause names to be resolved in the "my_schema"

You can try using the search_path setting in PostgreSQL. You can set it in your application.properties file like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am using this property for default tenant. But, when it comes to executing queries for other tenants, this approach won't work. Somehow, I have to change this property on the fly

Comment: You can try using a TenantAwareRoutingDataSource. This will allow you to set the search_path on a per-tenant basis.

Comment: @ŞükrüAYDINLIK: You can even change the search_path multi times within a single transaction. Whatever you need, just do it, it's standard functionality. SET search_path TO some_schema;

Comment: @Frank Heikens how can achieve such a behaviour? How can I interfere before every query?

Comment: @ŞükrüAYDINLIK: execute a query like this: SET search_path TO something;